Which function has a property $f'(x) = f(x) \cdot \int_0^x f(t)dt $?
I want to know if there exists a function satisfying
$$ f'(x) = f(x) \cdot \int_0^x f(t)dt $$
There are some facts from this equation:

$ f(x) = \exp\left( \displaystyle\int_0^x (x-t)f(t)dt \right)$ by integrating $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)dt$.
$\forall_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \  f(x) > 0$
$ f(0)=1$
$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left\{ \displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)dt \right\}^2 +1$

I don't expect we can find an explicit form of $f(x)$, but at least I hope we can guarantee the existance of $f(x)$.
Could you help me, please?

With $F(x) := \int_0^x f(t) , \mathrm{d}t$ we get $F''(x) = F'(x) F(x)$, i.e., a differential equation. It should not be too hard to prove existence of a solution.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2927060/42969

@gerw Then we get $ F(x) = \sqrt{2} \tan \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$. Thank you!

@gerw I have one more question. Can we find out $f(x)=f(-x)$ without knowing the explicit form $f(x) = \sec^2 \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$?

If f(x)=f(-x) then f'(x)=-f'(-x), $f'(-x)=f(-x)\int_0^{-x}f(t)dt=-f(x)\int_{-x}^0 f(t)dt=-f(x)\int_0^x f(t)dt=-f'(x)$ so yes

@Goaki. We need to show $f'(x)=-f'(x)$ without assuming $f(x)=f(-x)$. Is there any evidence for $f(-x)=\int_0^{-x} f(t)dt = -f(x) \int_{-x}^0 f(t)dt$?

Let
$$ y=\int_0^xf(t)dt. $$
Then
$$ y'=f(x), y''=f'(x)$$
and hence the equation becomes
$$ y''=y'y \tag1$$
in which $x$ is missing. Clearly $y(0)=0$. Let $p=y'$. Then
$$ y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=p\frac{dp}{dy} $$
and hence (1) becomes
$$ p\frac{dp}{dy}=py. $$
From the above, one has either $p=0$ or $\frac{dp}{dy}=y$.
Case 1: $p=0$. Then $y'=0$ and so $f(x)=0$.
Case 2: $\frac{dp}{dy}=y$. Then $dp=ydy$ and so $p=\frac12 y^2+\frac12C_1$.  Therefore
$$ y'=\frac12 y^2+\frac12C_1 \text{ or }\frac{dy}{y^2+C_1}=\frac12dx$$
from which one has
$$ x=2\int \frac{dy}{y^2+C_1}+C_2=\frac2{C_1}\arctan(\frac{y}{C_1})+C_2. $$
Using $y(0)=0$, one has $C_2=0$. So
$$ y=C_1\tan(\frac12C_1x). $$
Therefore
$$ f(x)=\frac12C_1^2\sec^2(\frac12C_1x). $$
