Showing the symmetry of $y'$ with $y''=y'y$
In my another question Which function has a property $f'(x) = f(x) \cdot \int_0^x f(t)dt $? ,
I could get an answer $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt =\sqrt{2} \tan\left( \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) $ and $f(x) = \sec^2 \left( \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$ by solving $F''(x) = F'(x)F(x)$.
These explicit form shows that $f(x)$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis.
But I am wondering if we can show the symmetry of $f(x)$ without finding the explicit solution of ODE.
There are some properties we can use:

$ f(x) = \exp\left( \displaystyle\int_0^x (x-t)f(t)dt \right)$ by integrating $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)dt$.
$\forall_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \  f(x) > 0$
$ f(0)=1$
$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left\{ \displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)dt \right\}^2 +1$

By substituting $-x$, we have
$$ f(-x) = \exp\left(\int_0^{-x} (-x-t)f(t)dt\right) = \exp \left( \int_0^x (x-s)f(-s)ds \right)$$
$$ f(-x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left\{ \int_0^{-x} f(t)dt \right\}^2 +1 = \dfrac{1}{2} \left\{ \int_0^{x} f(-s)ds \right\}^2 +1$$
but I have no idea to show $f(x)=f(-x)$.
Could you please help me?

Edit: The solutions of $y''=y'y$ are

$y=2a\tan(ax+b)$
$y=-2a\coth(ax+b)$
$y=-2a\tanh(ax+b)$
$y=-\dfrac{2}{x+c}$
$y=c$

for arbitrary constants $a$, $b$ and $c$.
Here, we have an initial condition
$$y(0)=F(0)=\int_0^0 f(t)dt = 0$$
and
$$ y'(0)=f(0)=1 $$
So we can eliminate the cases #2, #3, #4 and #5.
Then the case #1 satisfies $y'(x)=f(x)=f(-x)=y'(-x)$.
I want to show this property by using
$$ f'(x) = f(x) \int_0^x f(t)dt $$
without finding the exact solutions.

A little remark : Your title and your body has a little discrepancy. The title asks for symmetry of $y$ (which is $F$ in the body), whereas in the body it seems like you are asking about the symmetry of $f$, which is $F'$.

If you solve this as an autonomous ODE I think you get a different solution for $y'$.

@NeutralElement Is it $F(x)=- \tanh \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$ and $F(x) = -\dfrac{1}{\tanh \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)}$? I know these solutions, but they still has the same symmetry. (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927060/solution-to-this-differential-equation-fx-fxfx-needed)

@okw1124  Like $y=-2/x$. If you want y' to be even just make the change of variable x->-x

@NeutralElement Yes, that could be another solution, but $y'=\frac{2}{x^2}$ is still symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. This symmetry seems to be true regardless of the form of $y$, and it is why I asked about showing the symmetry of $y'$ 'without' finding an explicit solution.

What about $y=-2/(x+1)$

@NeutralElement In fact, it cannot be the exact solution since $y(0) \neq 0$.

With the newly imposed initial conditions, we can try the following.
We have $$y''=y'y,\ y(0)=0,\ y'(0)=1$$ and our goal is $$y'(-x)=y'(x)$$
I will assume that the solution to this differential equation exists and is unique. Then define $z(x)=-y(-x)$. On differentiating, we have $$z'(x)=y'(-x)$$ Then $$z''(x)=-y''(-x)=-y'(-x)y(-x)=y'(-x)(-y(-x))=z'(x)z(x)$$ Checking the boundary conditions, we see $$z(0)=-y(0)=0$$ $$z'(0)=y'(0)=1$$
Thus $y$ and $z$ satisfy the same differential equation with the same boundary conditions and hence $z=y$ implying $z'=y'$. Hence $$y'(-x)=y'(x)$$ and we are done.
